# How to Nifi ExecuteScript return attribute without prefix 'u' code python?

Tags: python, json, unicode, apache-nifi, processor

I have a json data incoming and I use ***ExecuteScript*** with ***Python*** code to extract key and value of this json data then put them into Attribute. Here my code:

```
import json
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class StreamCallback(StreamCallback):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        data = json.loads(text)
        for key in data:
            first = key
            break
        content = data[first]
        viewFlowFile = session.create()
        viewFlowFile = session.putAllAttributes(viewFlowFile,{'project': str(first), 'content': str(content)})
        session.transfer(viewFlowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:

    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, StreamCallback())
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
    session.commit()
```

When I run Job ***ExecuteScript*** returns string with prefix 'u'.

My input:

> {
>       "project_1": {
>           "device_code": "V001",
>           "line_code": "Anodiziing 12L"}}

and the output of ***content*** Attribute:

> {
>           u'device_code': u'V001',
>           u'line_code': u'Anodiziing 12L'}

I also tried add

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

on header of body code. But there is no change.

**My question is how to return string correctly without prefix 'u' using ExecuteScript Nifi?**

**Updated:**
We need convert type of data from dictionary to string.
Using `json.dumps(content)` instead of `str(content)` and output will have no prefix 'u'.

Comment: you did not specify what's wrong.

Comment: `json` strings are Unicode.  The `u''` is just an indicator that the dictionary you are printing contains Unicode strings.  If you don't want to see them, print the strings directly.  If you were running Python 3, it doesn't use `u''` for Unicode strings, as they are the default, but you would see `b''` for byte strings.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, thank you. After convert dictionary to string and put it directly, output has no prefix 'u' as my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON strings are Unicode. The u'' is just an indicator that the dictionary you are printing contains Unicode strings. If you don't want to see them, print the strings directly. If you were running Python 3, it doesn't use u'' for Unicode strings, as they are the default, but you would see b'' for byte strings.